# update panel not working in visual webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

I am trying to use update panel in visual webpart(farm solution only) but when i click on button nothing happens

```
<div>

     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
                   <section id="sec1" class="myclass1">
        <div class="mytit">
            <h2 >Header</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="mydiv" runat="server" >

        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <a class="btn " href="#" role="button" id="btnLoadData"  runat="server" OnServerClick="btnLoadData_Click" >Show rows</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
         </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on click event

```
 protected void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ShowData();

    }
```

When i click on button nothing happens and no error in console. If i remove update panel and click on button then it loads data. What is issue here?

Comment: Do you have anything else on your page apart from this webpart?

Comment: @AsadRefai i have lot of  other html controls which i have put in code above

Comment: Yes thats correct, I meant do you have any other SharePoint's OOB webparts like `CSWP` etc. Also have you registered the ajax assembly in your control and placed `script manager` ?

Comment: @AsadRefai what do you mean script manager and where to put it?

Comment: @AsadRefai i now tried to add scriptmanager in my myusercontrol.ascx  like <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />    But got error that u should have only script manager on page

Comment: Yes I guess thats because SharePoint Master pages have one. So dont worry of adding it on your `.ascx` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26959/discussion-between-happy-and-asad-refai).

Comment: Do you have a custom masterpage for your site

Answer (score 0):

May be your `href="#"` is creating your problem. Try to replace it with `href="javascript:void(0);"`.

Best approach would be to use `asp.net` controls like `asp:button` or `asp.LinkButton` instead of pure html `a`, here you will not be required to place some extra efforts.

Comment: i have found reason why its not working but dont know how to fix. Its cAUSING because of my master page. While activating feature i set my master page as default. I tried to deactivate feature and then check the page. Update panel works. So its something in master page which is blocking

Comment: Happy, I am facing the same problem as you with the masterpage. Have you found a solution ?